# Backlight keyboard won't turn on samsung ativbook 6 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, brightness, samsung, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I like it, but I can't seem to get the backlight in the keyboard to work. I have searched hours for a solution, but I can't find the right command -- perhaps something that references `kbd_brightness`.

Is there a way to test if this is a command/feature that can be used to manage/change the backlight setting?

I don't know what else to do, everything worked fine on win8.

If it is of any use, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on UEFI alongside win8.1.  I can turn the keyboard backlight on in win8.1. Every solution that I have read so far has to do with the `kbd_brightness` thing which appears only when I boot from the original usb from were Ubuntu was installed, but the option isn't there when I boot without it.

I have thought that maybe I could just copy that missing file from the usb boot and replace it, but I don't know where to put it or if it has any hope of working.

Comment: have you tried contacting the vendor directly?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather post as a comment but I can't. Have you tried this command in a shell console?

```
sudo xset led 3
```

I have a desktop coolermaster backlit keyboard, and that's the only way I have been able to turn it on. Worth a try.